# long shot with IE compatibility mode and page posting

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple asp.net page that contains a file upload element. When I'm in IE compatibility mode the page posts back to server fine. However, if I disable compatibility mode for some reason my code never reaches the server. Its failing somewhere in client code.

I know this is not a lot to go on but does anyone know off the top what I could look at to see what's happening?

Comment: Look in the developer tools.

Comment: F12 key from your keyboard. Press script button and have a look at the cosnole on the right of the opened window.

Comment: I tried stepping through the javascript code but there's some multi-threading going and I just get lost. What can cause IE client-side code to fail posting back to server when not in compatibility mode?